# MySQL Replication with Data Transformation and Replicant-specific Data

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0

I have two MySQL 8.0.23 RDS's - one "Production" RDS that actual users use, and one "Performance" RDS that is used for performance testing.

These databases have the same schema and tables (with the same indexes, foreign keys, etc). The Performance RDS was also created off of a snapshot of the Production RDS, so the Production and Performance RDS's share a lot of data.

It has been around a year since the Performance database was created off of the Production database's snapshot, so the data between the two has drifted apart. The Production RDS has data that the Performance RDS does not. Similarly, the Performance RDS has several thousand rows of testing-related data that was added to it over the past year.

I want to automatically replicate data from the Production database to the Performance database, but with the following caveats:

1. I want to be able to add data to **only** the Performance RDS, without replication overwriting it (in order to generate test users for our performance tests).
2. I want to transform some of the data replicating from the Production RDS to the Performance RDS (for example, I'd like to obfuscate user emails before they go to the Performance RDS).
3. I'd like to fully sync the databases again 1 time, then have ongoing changes continuously replicated to the Performance RDS (maybe once a week).

I'm wondering, is this even possible with MySQL replication? It seems like the 1st point above might be impossible, as that would add a risk of data collisions if we use auto-increment keys and our extra data is in the same tables as replicated tables. Does MySQL Replication provide a way to get around that?

Comment: What you describe is not "replication". You'll have to build a custom ETL process to implement all your requirements.

Comment: @mustaccio Okay I'll keep that in mind - maybe I'll start studying AWS Glue to see if that might fit our use case